# How to achieve Quake moving lava effect using OpenGL under v2.0?

Tags: opengl, shaders, support

On the first boss fight level you could notice how lava moves what is not a surprise for a software renderer. But according to the Quake fandom, GLQuake was released in 1997, hence OpenGL had no shader support, so how the moving lava was added? Was it some kind of a mesh grid with just some texture-mapped polys floating around? Or maybe it was still done in the 'software rendered' way?

[image: Quake's the first boss]

Comment: How game X did thing Y type questions are generally not on topic here. It is very much on topic to ask how you could achieve a similar result - if that's what you're after, please edit your question to reflect that. Be sure to include information about your game's constraints to help focus answers on relevant solutions.

Comment: I modified the title, hope it became more correct. Thanks for the amendment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is to adjust the UV coordinates. Here are a couple of non-shader options for doing that:

1. Just modify the mesh on the CPU every frame. This is straightforward if you're using glTexCoord2f() etc. instead of vertex buffers.
2. Apply a transform matrix using glMatrixMode(GL_TEXTURE). This would work for things like scrolling a texture across a mesh, but it's less flexible.

Having said all that, you could just take look at the source code: https://github.com/id-Software/Quake

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Indeed, the first one is **the most** straightforward, I haven't thought of it somehow. The second approach seems to be an interesting one.

Won't lie, it is a bit hard for me to find the answer in the source without knowing the exact file.